# Pandas add count and column with list after groupby

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have the following dataframe `df`:

```
Month       Cat Constr  Part
1/1/2021    asd v1      p1
1/1/2021    asd v1      p2
1/1/2021    asd v2      p1
1/1/2021    pqr v1      p1
1/1/2021    pqr v1      p2
1/1/2021    pqr v2      p2
```

I am trying to achieve the following:

```
Month       Cat Constr  count   part
1/1/2021    asd v1      2       [p1, p2]
1/1/2021    asd v2      1       [p1]
1/1/2021    pqr v1      2       [p1,p2]
1/1/2021    pqr v2      1       [p2]
```

To get the count column I do the following:

```
df.groupby(['Month', 'Cat', 'Constr']).agg(['count'])
```

But I am not sure how to add the list of `Part` who are part of `groupby`

I am trying to do group by `['Month', 'Cat', 'Constr']` and find the number of `Part` for each groupby unique combination and a list of `Part` which form that group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` as you did but apply `list`:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Month', 'Cat Constr']).agg(list).reset_index()

       Month Cat Constr      Part
0 2021-01-01     asd v1  [p1, p2]
1 2021-01-01     asd v2      [p1]
2 2021-01-01     pqr v1  [p1, p2]
3 2021-01-01     pqr v2      [p2]
```

To get all together:

```
>>> df.groupby(['Month', 'Cat Constr'])['Part'] \
      .agg(count='count', part=list)

       Month Cat Constr  count      part
0 2021-01-01     asd v1      2  [p1, p2]
1 2021-01-01     asd v2      1      [p1]
2 2021-01-01     pqr v1      2  [p1, p2]
3 2021-01-01     pqr v2      1      [p2]
```